# how to permanently show selected tray icons

Tags: windows-10, notification-area

*i can't believe, that i didn't find an existing question or not even anywhere else something about this topic in the internet... so please forgive me if this is a duplicate.*

the problem is, that even if you set a tray icon to be shown in windows 10, it silently disappears again after a program update.
**is there a way, that you don't have to re-enable/rearranging the tray icon after every update and still have just a set of chosen tray icons visible?**

---

i know, you can show all tray icons by activating it in the settings or using `Set-ItemProperty "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer" -Name "EnableAutoTray" -Value "0"`, but that's too much!
i just want 2 selected icons to be shown anytime, no mater what updates got installed. - *i (not using windows) can't believe that this isn't possible and it seems that nobody cares?!? well... "at least" it drives some of my noobs nuts, rearranging the icons every few weeks. :-/*

Comment: *if this is the intended behavior, this defeats the purpose of tray icons resp. the tray icon area; or at least makes it pretty tedious to use it reasonably. IMHO a tray area should show all important information for the user within a glimpse and ideally without clicking around once or even fiddling around every now and then.*

Comment: If you set your displayed and hidden icons using the little UP arrow in in the System Tray (^) , such changes are essentially permanent. Changes (Updates) to Windows and Apps do not change my icon settings.

Comment: @John: hmmm... "interesting": no mater if they move the icons via drag&drop or settings into the taskbar, after the program got an update, the icon is hidden again. - and this happens with 2 completely different programs on at least 2-3 different machines. :-( **||** *if i would have experienced it otherwise at least once, i wouldn't have asked such a dumb question...*

Comment: In a long time, I have not seen this happen, so it may be the particular apps you are using. Apps like Office and comparable Apps do not do this on my machines here.

Comment: @John: i've got reports, that this is happening with [Nextcloud](https://nextcloud.com/install/#install-clients) and [Element](https://element.io/get-started). - this does not mean that it doesn't happen with other programs! ...but these are the 2, my noobs care about and want to have in the system tray all the time.